# Can ANTLR grammar files be modularised?

Tags: antlr

I am building ANTLR3 applications where some of the same grammar rules are likely to be used in different applications. There will be many *.g files but they may, for example, all wish to reference the same version of FLOAT. Are there "import" facilities whereby a *.g can be assembled from other *.g files and if so what are the precedence rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean [composite grammars](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Composite+Grammars)?

Comment: This is what I think I am looking for, thanks. I don't think it is mentioned in the ANTLR reference and I assume it's fairly recent from reading the wiki page you mention. Assuming my import strategy is DAG-like it should be tractable.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find it in my copy of the *ANTLR reference* either, but I stumbled upon this while browsing the ANTLR wiki recently.